# Combine string elements within a list into one variable in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) with one variable that's a list containing string vectors (mylist).

```
v1 = c("a", "b", "c")
v2 = c("d", "e", "f", "g", "h")
v3 = c("x", "y", "z", "k")

df = tibble(id = seq(1:3), mylist = list(v1, v2, v3))
```

How can I combine the elements of mylist into a single variable for each row? I want my data to look like this:

```
id mylist
1  "a b c"
2  "d e f g h"
3  "x y z k"
```

Answer (score 2):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(mylist = Reduce(paste, mylist))

     id mylist   
  <int> <chr>    
1     1 a b c    
2     2 d e f g h
3     3 x y z k
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option would be to use collapse the list elements using `sapply()` and `paste()`:

```
df$mylist <- sapply(mylist, paste, collapse = " ")
df

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id mylist   
  <int> <chr>    
1     1 a b c    
2     2 d e f g h
3     3 x y z k
```

Or, using `dplyr` with `purrr::map_chr()`:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr) 

df %>%
  mutate(mylist = map_chr(mylist, paste, collapse = " "))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to `unnest` and do a `group_by` `paste`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    # // expand the dataset by unnesting the column
    unnest(c(mylist)) %>%
    # // grouped by id
    group_by(id) %>% 
    # // paste the elements of mylist to a single string
    summarise(mylist = str_c(mylist, collapse=' '))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    id mylist   
#  <int> <chr>    
#1     1 a b c    
#2     2 d e f g h
#3     3 x y z k
```